# Hooking up my compressor to my dryer outlet

Tags: dryer, compressor

I need to plug in my compressor, which has a NEMA L6-30P plug.

[image]

I currently have a NEMA 10-30R Receptacle [image]

How do I do this? It looks like the ground from my dryer plug is grounded in the box. I do have a rod that runs into the ground outside my house. Can I run a separate plug off my dryer plug and attach it right next to the dryer plug for my compressor? They both won't be running at the same time.

**Edited in from comments on an answer:**

- The dryer plug is in a metal box that runs through a foot of metal conduit up to the electrical box that runs to a 30 amp breaker.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Despite the edit (well done), it's still a bit difficult to decipher what you're trying to do. At a minimum we need the electrical requirement info on the compressor. Are you flat out of outlets in the house, so you want to share the outlet with the dryer? Do you want to extend the dryer's circuit to add an additional outlet? Feel free to [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Does your dryer plug have a metal box which is connected to a metal electrical cable or conduit?  If so, the ground may be fine.  You could *carefully* test it using a VOM or a *three-light tester* and probes.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=NEMA+L6-30P+to+10-30r

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of *your* dryer receptacle box please?

Comment: Pics https://imgur.com/a/rTJu4Zw

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/RhAjn3Q

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/fXu6Io2

Comment: Is this a service or a sub-panel?

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/RhAjn3Q thats inside my dryer outlet

Comment: This is my breaker box on inside of house . This box has the wires running to a main shut off panel on the outside of my house that my power connect to outside.

Comment: No sub panels this is the only breaker box that service my house. Runs outside to the meter http://imgur.com/gallery/4UG8KIF

Answer (score 3):

Given the proximity of the 10-30R receptacle to the panel, and the presence of conduit connecting the two, you could upgrade the 10-30R to a 14-30R and likewise swap out the power cord on the dryer. That's something like US$25 in parts. This is an upgrade that is just good sense to implement.

If you upgrade to a 14-30R then you could easily make or buy an adapter from the 14-30P to L6-30R. It would deal with the ground-vs-neutral situation correctly.

There's also another option. Since the panel is just right there, get a bit of conduit and a box and install a new L6-30R receptacle. I believe code allows multiple 30A receptacles to be fed from a 30A breaker. If the panel has no room for a new breaker and you don't want to replace existing breakers with a quad breaker solution, you could choose to feed both receptacles from the one existing breaker. The terminal on your breaker might be designed for landing two conductors, but if not, attach a pigtail of wire to the breaker and use a wire nut to join the pigtail with the leads going to the two receptacles (times two: this same arrangement for both poles of the breaker).

The two-receptacles-one-breaker arrangement could be accomplished by putting the junction in the box with the dryer outlet but it might violate box fill rules and definitely would be crowded and hard to work with. It'll be much easier to run the conductors from a new receptacle directly into the breaker box and make the junction there.

Comment: Absolutely! That NEMA 10 connection is a child-killer.  For any dryer connected NEMA 10, a single point of failure (loose neutral connection) *WILL* energize the chassis of the dryer.  What are the chances of someone touching that and a grounded thing? *The washing machine chassis is grounded*.

Comment: And part of changing the cord on the dryer must be removing the neutral-to-ground bonding strap.  Tie it down somewhere safe that isn't the neutral pole :)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't legally tap wire for wire from the receptacle, the NEMA 6 is two hots and a ground, NEMA 10 is two hots and a **neutral** that by special exception allows grounding via the neutral conductor (NEC 250.140 exception). If you just even had the compressor plugged in you would be exposing dryer current to the compressor ground.

You could run a ground wire from the panel through the dryer outlet box, but then you no longer satisfy the NEMA 10 exception which specifies "where an equipment grounding conductor is not present", so you would have to replace your dryer receptacle and cord with a safer NEMA 14.

From your description in the comments to other answer I don't think your NEMA 10 is legal at all. The exception allows the metal box to be connected to the neutral, but the section doesn't specify grounding metal raceway, ostensibly since then an equipment ground is present. I realize existing installations are subject to the code at the time of install, but I doubt the 10 was ever legal with grounding raceway.

Comment: It was never illegal to use EMT conduit. And there *was* a point in time when it was legal to install a NEMA 10 recep in any installation including EMT conduit.  However, the NEMA 10 neutral was still neutral and required an insulated white wire.  You could not use EMT shell as a neutral substitute.  OP should convert the recep and dryer to NEMA 14, and then will be free to use a NEMA 6-NEMA 14 adapter cable; that particular cable is legal.

Comment: Ok guys sorry been little busy this is what I have going on

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/fXu6Io2

Comment: There are some pics of what I have going on. And that strip all the grounds run to isn't that the ground strip on neutral. And the box is grounded to a rod that runs outside and into the ground

Comment: You got big problems here, bonded neutral is only legal at service, and you have way more than 6 main disconnects allowed in a service panel.  And you have breakers not NRTL approved for the panel.

Comment: So I had this house inspected by a lic inspector he said all the wiring was up to code he checked all of it

Comment: This is the service box for my house

Comment: There is a big change for 2020, but this doesn't satisfy NEC 230.71 now or before. https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70

Comment: https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=844.0

Comment: So my  main disconnect runs right off my electrical meter then into my breaker box. So to clean this up what kind of box should I upgrade and id like a box I can add more breaker to

Comment: If the disconnect ahead of this is the "service" then the neutral to this panel needs to be separate from the ground and then would be OK. If the disconnect is only an NEC 230.85 Emergency Disconnect (Firemans Disconnect) then you need a "service" rated panel with a main breaker. I would buy a Siemens so you could re-use most of your breakers. I can't determine for sure the main breaker size without examining meter and other service equipment, but probably a 200A. Sometimes a 40 space value pack is cheaper than a 30 space. Model #SN4040B1200P1

Answer (score -4):

Simple answer is yes if they are both 240v.

Comment: Ok so the dryer plug is in a metal little box that runs through a foot of metal tube up to the electrical box that runs to a 30 amp breaker. The ground is ran to a strip in the breaker box that is in line with all the other grounds. I dont have anymore breakers to run a extra breaker for my compressor.

Comment: Compressor says 230volt. The plug on compressor says 30a-250v 3prong nema L6-30. Dryer plug is the 3 prong 10-30r

Comment: Don't hold discussions via backchannels. Post your images here. You were advised to upload to https://imgur.com and link here.

Comment: A TL;DR section is good, however, a little more meat is considered very helpful.

Comment: Pics https://imgur.com/a/rTJu4Zw

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/RhAjn3Q